# Pandas: merge 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dateframes, [dfItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxNzF.png) and [dfCustomers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Uyrn.png), that I want to merge. dfItem consists of invoices over a ten year period, while dfCustomers consist of the customer number and customer name.

I want to create a new df where the corresponding kundenavn (customer name) is added to each row on dfItem. The common column is kundenummer (customer number).

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: This will help https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you wanted?

```
result = dfItem.merge(dfCustomers, how='left', on=['kundenummer'])
```

Comment: This produces the desired layout but all the values in the series 'kundenavn' (customer name) are NaN. Should I revise my question or is the info supplied adequate?

Comment: Data that you provided doesn't have any match in `'kundenummer'`. `JOIN` or `merge` in `pandas` works by matching same column values and returns `NaN` if value is not found.

Comment: Thank you. You pointed me in the right direction. Both of my data frames included a  a string in the column 'kundenummer' that I didn't know about. Your solution worked after removing the strings. How do I mark your answer as correct? PS: I have been trying to figure this out for several days now and I finally got around to ask for help. THANK YOU :)

Comment: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/345643) should be helpful. And you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be better if you provided more info but i guess this will do according to the information you provided

```
df=pd.merge( dfItem ,dfCustomers,on=[' kundenummer'])
```